# How to return string by value C++ with move semantics?

Tags: c++, string, copy-constructor, move-semantics, nrvo

I want to have a function that returns a string by value, and i want to move construct another string from that return value. When NRVO/RVO is invoked, the move construktor works fine, no copy is made, but when I can't rely on NRVO, the function makes a copy of the string, even when I explicitly move the return value.

I print values of the raw data adress to check whether a copy was made.

Here is the code:

```
void printStringAdr(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << (void*)s.data() << std::endl;
}

std::string getStringNRVO() 
{
    std::string str("text");
    printStringAdr(str);
    return str; //works fine, no copy
}

std::string getStringNoNRVO() 
{
    std::string str1("ABC");
    std::string str2("XYZ");

    if (rand() % 2)
    {
        printStringAdr(str1);
        return str1; //makes copy
    }
    else
    {
        printStringAdr(str2);
        return str2; //makes copy
    }
}

std::string getStringNoNRVO_ForceMove()
{
    std::string str1("ABC");
    std::string str2("XYZ");

    std::string* strptr = &str1;

    if (rand() % 2)
        strptr = &str2;

    printStringAdr(*strptr);
    return std::move(*strptr); //doesn't work, makes copy
}


int main()
{
    std::string s = getStringNRVO(); //only this function works like i expect
    printStringAdr(s);
}
```

Comment: You might detect small string optimizations here.

Comment: Can't reproduce that with libstdc++; but libstdc++ uses shared (COW) strings anyway IIRC, so that's not reliable.

Comment: Some string implementations use a union containing a pointer and a buffer (say 8 bytes) to hold small strings instead of allocating memory for them. Try using bigger strings to see if this is causing your results to be incorrect.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was not aware of small string optimizations. All three functions work properly with large strings. Also I have noticed that when a strptr is dereferenced it needs to be explicitly moved, but str1 and str2 don't. Does that mean that the compiler treats local values as rvalues in the return statement, but when a object is dereferenced it isn't sure what it contains so it copies it?

Comment: @vladimirm Roughly, yes. If the preconditions for copy elision apply for a return statement, save for the fact that the returned variable can also be a parameter, the compiler *tries* to treat it as an rvalue (if that fails, it treats it as an lvalue). The preconditions don't apply if the expression in the return statement is not *the name* of a local variable.